# Usar SweetAlert2 en un echo

Tags: php, html, echo

Quisiera integrar sweetAlert en mi `echo`

```
<script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11'></script>
<?php
include '../../connection.php';
if (isset($_POST['RegistrarCultivo'])) {
    $cultivo = $_POST['cultivo'];
    $sqlusuario = "INSERT INTO cultivo(Cultivo) 
   VALUES ('$cultivo')";
    $INSERCION = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlusuario);
    echo "
    <script>
     Swal.fire({
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Se registro con exito',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500
      })
      window.location = '../admin/admin-add-map.php';
  </script>";

}
```

Si lo uso así no corre y ya lo ya verifique que si corra SweetAlert en la consola del navegador y no tiene problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pueden ayudar a usarlo en el `echo`

Comment: Mala cosa poner código JS en el contexto de PHP. Considera usar Ajax o la API Fetch. Sea como sea, el error parece decir que no estás en el `body`, prueba a poner la etiqueta `body` en la salida, aunque repito, mala cosa esa mezcla.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias, si funciono. Es que no se mucho y estoy empezando con un proyecto escolar

Comment: Ya, poco a poco se va aprendiendo. El asunto es que tu `script` debería estar en el contexto del cliente, y mostrarse allí una vez el código del servidor sea procesado. Si usas Ajax o la API Fetch, puedes recoger la respuesta del servidor (desde el cliente) y mostrar la alerta. Además, todo eso ocurrirá sin tener que recargar la página, ahorrando recursos y creando un código sumamente elegante.